# How to replace a git repository?

Tags: git, github, repository

I created a git repository and updated it with some stuff. Later I created a new directory for this project and initialized new git for it. Now I want to push changes and replace the old contents in the repository. When I run `git push origin master` I get

```
! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@github.com:Username/repo2.git'
To prevent you from losing history, non-fast-forward updates were rejected
Merge the remote changes before pushing again.  See the 'Note about
fast-forwards' section of 'git push --help' for details.
```

What can I do to solve this?

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8461528/replace-github-repo-while-preserving-issues-wiki-etc

Answer (score 54, accepted):

You just need to use a little force:

`git push --force origin master`

`--force` can also be abbreviated to `-f`.

Comment: What if one wants to keep previous commits and just add new things from new repo as another commit?

Comment: @Defozo, see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41276328/3681880).