# Add existing Android Studio project to existing GitHub repository

Tags: git, android-studio, github

I've created a project new project in Android Studio and I want to add it to an existing GitHub repository which is currently empty.

I have tried the answer from this question: [Replace GitHub repository with a new Android Studio project while preserving old commits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41276327/replace-github-repository-with-a-new-android-studio-project-while-preserving-old/41276328#41276328)
but once I get to the final `git push` I get an error saying `fatal: No configured push destination.`

I have also tried https://github.community/t5/How-to-use-Git-and-GitHub/How-to-link-an-existing-Android-Studio-Project-to-an-existing/td-p/1946 but this uploads the project to the wrong GitHub account. I have two GitHub accounts which I think was the problem for this solution and I have since logged out of the account I don't need.

Are there any other ways to connect to an existing GitHub repository?

Answer (score 6):

Most probably you forgot to add a remote. you can check your list of remote using the following command.

```
 git remote -v
```

If there exist no origin, try add a remote using:

```
git remote add <remote name> <remote url>
```

(Remote url is your repository url, for example: https://github.com/user/repo.git)

Then you can push using the following command:

```
git push <remote name> <your branch name>
```

Answer (score 3):

The first thing you have to do is to create your local repository (on your machine)

```
git init
```

As you are trying to do a `git push`, I assume you already have done that.
So the next thing you have to do is to define a remote repository (github) for your local repository to push on :

```
git remote add origin https://github.com/<user>/<repo>.git
```

You then can do your `push` but with a few more paramters.

```
git push -u origin master
```

That will tell git to push your commits to the `master` branch on your `origin` remote repository

More information on `git remote` here : https://help.github.com/articles/adding-a-remote/

Answer (score 0):

**Steps...**

> git init
>
> git remote set-url origin git@github.com:username/repo.git
>
> git add .
>
> git commit -m "my commit"
>
> git push origin master